# Python MySQL connection lost inside Docker container

Tags: python, mysql, docker

I have a script that queries four separate MySQL databases (hosted elsewhere) using Python (with `mysql-connector==2.2.9`). I wrote and tested this script locally, and it runs without issue on my MacBook. I then created a Docker image using `ubuntu:18.04` as the base image, and would like to run this script inside the container. Starting the container locally, it queries the first DB without issue, but I get the following error on the second DB:

`mysql.connector.errors.InterfaceError: 2013: Lost connection to MySQL server during query`

This *only* happens inside the container. The relevant code snippit:

```
for i, host in enumerate(hosts):
    cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user=os.environ["DBUSER"],
                                  password=os.environ["DBPASSWORD"],
                                  host=host,
                                  database=XXXXX
                                  )
    cursor = cnx.cursor()
    cursor.execute(query)
    df = pd.DataFrame(cursor.fetchall(), columns=columns)
```

Because the same code runs without issue outside of the container, I don't believe the issue is on the server. Additionally, most of the timeout parameters on the server seem fine. Querying `show session variables like '%timeout';` returns the following:

```
('delayed_insert_timeout', '300')
('have_statement_timeout', 'YES')
('innodb_flush_log_at_timeout', '1')
('innodb_lock_wait_timeout', '50')
('innodb_rollback_on_timeout', 'OFF')
('interactive_timeout', '7200')
('lock_wait_timeout', '31536000')
('net_read_timeout', '600')
('net_write_timeout', '600')
('rpl_stop_slave_timeout', '31536000')
('slave_net_timeout', '3600')
('thread_pool_idle_timeout', '60')
('wait_timeout', '7200')
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: You ever figure this out @Tim? I'm facing this exact issue now and unable to puzzle it out.

Answer (score 0):

You do not provide much relevant information save for the fact that your code works outside of the docker container and not inside. It is however very likely that the hostname of the database is not recognized inside of the container. Try using IP address for your "host". Or if not possible, use modified /etc/hosts mounted inside of the container.

Comment: I can certainly try, but it seems unlikely because of the fact that my query runs against the first host without problems, but times out on the second.